# Analytic function on circle

Tags: real-analysis

A function is real analytic on a set $D$ in $\mathbb{R}$ if it can be represented by power series locally. But if a function is analytic on a circle, can it be represented by a power series at the center of the circle?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are asking if an analytic function on an interval of the form $(c-R,c+R)$ can be globally represented by a power series centered at $c$. The answer is no.

Indeed, consider the function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+x^{2}}.$

$f$ is analytic on all of $\mathbb{R}$, therefore it is analytic on the interval $(-10,10)$, for instance. Its power series expansion at $c=0$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n} x^{2n}$$ but, as you can check, this series only converges on the interval $(-1,1)$.